# Recommendation for laptop for photo editing

Tags: laptop

I want to purchase a laptop for my job. I need it to do photo editing and short film editing.

- Main programs I use are Adobe products
- I need an FHD 1920x1080 screen, processor needs to be an i7
- My budget is around $600

Comment: How big of a screen do you need?

Comment: "Processor needs to be an i7" - does this mean you want the superior performance of a 4-core hyperthreaded processor or that you want the superior battery-longetivity of a 2-core hyperthreaded processor? i7 is a broad term for a number of high-binned chips.

Comment: Perhaps I would put some more money to be able to buy an Apple as they have probably the best screen for photo editing. Most of the cheapest notebooks comes with TN screen that does not really fit for the Photo edition.

Answer (score 1):

Two years ago now, I bought the Lenovo Y510p for 700€. You can find it at a lower price for now (in addition, I bought the version with a second GPU, which was a bit more expensive, instead of the optical drive).

I'm recommending this laptop because:

- Its in your price range
- It has a I7 4702MQ
- 8GB of ram which might be useful for Adobe products
- Has a FHD screen which had (at the time) good review about its contrast, colorimetry etc. wich is, I think, a good point for your usage.
- In addition to the Intel's IGB, you have a GT755m wich is useful for media works (at least for video editing).

I know Lenovo released its successor but it has a terrible screen (according to the tests I read 2 years ago).